Is it possible to select a specific boot configuration at boot on UEFI?
System: An AMD processor on a Gigabyte M550 motherboard configured for UEFI boot.
I have a Windows system that currently supports two users/use cases:

Flight Simulator.
This is specifically configured and optimized for Microsoft Flight Simulator and X-Plane 11/12. I have a vicious processor, an expensive video card, and heaping handfulls of RAM to make it as "game ready" as possible, especially for the demanding application of a flight simulator.

Online gaming by my granddaughters.
Since my system hardware is relatively advanced by normal standards, my granddaughters want to share the hardware when they visit to play Genshin Impact, AION, Minecraft, STEAM games, etc.


This was originally configured as a system with two users: Me for the flight sim stuff and another for the granddaughters.
This turned out to be a bad idea as their installs bleed-over and affect what I am doing.
The obvious, (and simplest), solution is to get them their own computer but here in Russia that's extremely expensive right now.
My idea is to create two different installs of Windows on completely separate drives, each as if it was the only drive on the system, (actually disconnect everything else when installing), and select between them at boot time such that the storage media used by one install completely disappears and is absolutely inaccessible to the other.
In the early PC days, (i.e. DOS), there was a utility called System Commander that would intercept the boot process via capturing the MBR and allow you to boot to multiple drives, allowing you to "hide" drives using the drive filesystem-type bytes to mask a system's drive hardware that needed to be inessential or that was necessary to hide from a different configuration.
System Commander did this by setting selected drives to a filesystem type that DOS wouldn't/couldn't mount, and then System Commander would boot the selected system configuration. The result was the ability to set up multiple boot configurations that acted as if they were completely separate computers.
Is this something available via UEFI?
I know I can allow Windows' boot manager to select the OS to boot, but how do I get it to make drives inaccessible?
Thanks!

The normal solution is multiple different user logon accounts, but games tend not to respect that and insist on being installed as Administrator.

And even worse, the Hoyoverse games like Genshin Impact insist on being RUN as Administrator too!


I know I can allow Windows' boot manager to select the OS to boot, but how do I get it to make drives inaccessible?

You don't – Windows does not rely on the firmware to detect drives anymore, instead directly scanning PCI/SATA/etc. devices (as most current operating systems do), which neither the firmware nor the bootloader have any opportunity to intercept. Likewise, it uses its own partition table parser and not the firmware's.
UEFI can allow you to select from different bootloaders (which might coexist on the same disk, as opposed to BIOS which only had a single MBR per disk), but it won't help you with hiding disks or other hardware.
Access to non-system disks can be controlled either by disabling the PCI or SATA device through Windows' "Device Manager" (devmgmt.msc) at the lower level, or by marking a disk as 'offline' through "Disk Management" (diskmgmt.msc) at higher level.

Hmm. Can something be done with different BitLocker configurations with different keys? Does feel like a nonsupported configuration though.

Sure, you can have two BitLocker volumes if you're feeling like it. I don't think it will have any problems.
